# Can't set watermark in Magento2 / How to change footer links?

Tags: magento2, watermark, footer-links

I tried to set watermark and thumbnail in Magento2, but its not adding the watermark / thumbnail to the productimages.

[image]

I did reindex everything, I did delete / flush every single cache (also image cache).

Anyone an idea? Magento 2.1 seems quite unstable..

I would also be happy if someone could explain me how to change the footer links, seems to be a pain in the ass..

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in M2.1 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5270?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container.

You need to enter Image Size in the full format e.g. 200x300

as this is still not fixed in M2.1.1 there is a temporary solution how to enter the correct "Image Size"

1. Go to your database with either phpmyadmin 
   or cli -> "mysql -u database_user -p database_name"
2. look for "core_config_data" table

   and find the following PATH:

   ```
   design/watermark/image_size

   design/watermark/small_image_size

   design/watermark/swatch_image_size

   design/watermark/thumbnail_size
   ```
3. set the VALUE manualy e.g. -> 200x300