# Watermark in Magento2 trouble

Tags: product-images, magento-2.1.7, watermark

My product images are not watermarked, no matter what settings I try in administration.

- www-data has the write permission to ./pub/media/catalog/product/watermark and successfully writes the files there.
- flush magento cache, "Flush Catalog Images Cache" and "Full page Caching" every time
- have set the sizes and opacity for every picture, without the bug [Can't set watermark in Magento2 / How to change footer links?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/136913/7773)

I run a Magento 2.1.7 with a custom theme. Since I still have the problem on the default "Blank theme", I am looking to the way Magento2 computes watermaks ( module may be missing with that settings?).

Thanks a lot by advance for any advices.

Comment: Found the problem: the settings were overridden at the store view level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add watermark to product images
Magento 2.0

```
On the Admin sidebar, Stores > Settings > Configuration.
```

Magento 2.1 or above

```
On the Admin sidebar, Content > Design > Configuration.
In the panel, General > Design.
Expand the Product Image Watermarks section and complete the following steps for the Base, Small, and Thumbnail images:
    Enter the Watermark Default Size in pixels.
    Enter the Watermark Opacity, Percent as a percentage.
    Click on Choose File, to upload the image file.
    Set Watermark Position to your preference.
```

How to upload Images Watermarks Product Watermark Config

```
When complete, click on Save.
Go to Cache Management to refresh the cache.
```

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful.

Comment: watermark image is not displaying at Product details page, working fine at product listing page.